# Execution of python script from sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am new to SharePoint usage, so sorry if my question seeems dumb, I did not yet find answer on the net.

I dropped a python script on SharePoint 2013 and want to run it from SharePoint.
When I clic on it I got 3 options, Open/Save/Cancel. If I choose to open, a window console briefly opens then closes, but I do not have time to see anything.
My script is a quizz, an automatic python script asking questions and giving answers at the end, it works correctly if I save it on my desktop and double-click on it for example.

If I cannot do that with python what are my solutions to run such a quizz directly from SharePoint ?

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot run python script from SharePoint. Use 'survey' out-of-box SharePoint feature.
 I didn't yet used this, may be there don't exists answer displaying. I think you can add answer by javascript code if it not exists.
See this link for [guide](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-survey-ea52a787-822e-4f7e-b5ed-77bb14df3aba)

Second way - repeat your logic in javascript code or create C# web part. Add this js code or web part to some SharePoint page. Your logic must save questions and people answers to SharePoint custom list or where you want.